# Is it possible to open Android Google Map voice search?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I would like to open this directly from my program, is it possbile?

[image]

I checked this, but cannot found relevant information

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents

If it is impossible, is there any alternative way?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that from your activity.
In the image above you can see a dialog that catches the voice of the user, this is  because Google Maps calling an intent `ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH`, and you can't start an intent and after calling Maps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the only documentation that I found on the internet for that question. [The Adding Voice Capabilities](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/voice.html). Just remember that these voice actions are task-based and are built into the Wear platform. So you need to use Android wear for that, see [Maps API on Android wear](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/wear).

Just read the two documentation to understand more. Also take note, that do not violate any [terms of service on the Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#10-license-restrictions). Here is one example [question](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-activate-voice-based-directions-using-Google-Map-API) for that.

So far, I have not used this voice capablities, so I'm not sure if it will really help you, but I think I give you a small idea with it. Goodluck and Happy coding :)